# AJAX jQuery MySQL PHP issues inserting to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, insert

I'm trying to add a comment to a database without refreshing. I managed to get data to enter into the database but somehow I broke it. I've followed a couple of tutorials and now I think I'm mixed up somewhere. It's probably something small.

I think it's the jQuery that is messed up.

So...
MySQL database is simple - comment_id, title, body

**HTML**

```
<form class="comment-form" action="php/addcomment.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Add Comment</h2>
                        <label for="comment_title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="comment_title" name="comment_title" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div><!--/formgroup-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment_body">Body</label>
                        <textarea name="comment_body" id="comment_body" class="form-control" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
                    </div><!--/formgroup-->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="comment-btn">Submit</button>
                </form><!--/form-->
```

**addcomment.php**

```
include('dbconnect.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

$title = $_POST['comment_title'];
$body = $_POST['comment_body'];

$sql = "insert into comments (title, body) values ('$title','$body')";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
echo 'success';
}
```

**jQuery AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //option A
        $("#comment-form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(e);
        });
    });

    $('#comment-btn').click(function(){
     $.post( 
     $('#comment_form').attr('action'),
     $('#comment_form :input').serializeArray(),
     function(result){
         $('#result2').html(result);
        }
     );
    });
```

If you want anymore info please dont hesitate to ask, any help would be much appreciated!
The database DOES connect btw i didn't feel as if i had to include dbconnect.php

Thanks!

[Form(HTML)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10klJ.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Any error message? What is "broked" ?

Comment: I just want it to work I really don't care about protection from SQL injections I just want to know how to fix it at this stage. I appreciate your knowledge but I just want a basic answer

Comment: no error messages

Comment: it should insert to database but it does not

Comment: Have you debugged the followed path by data? I mean, at what point, it is losing the control? try `dumping` the `post` data after each function or logic.

Comment: id #comment-form does not exist!

Comment: change `class="comment-form"`  to  `id="comment-form"` and lets see what happens.